# SSIS convert exponent number to real (DT_R4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, data-import

I have a flat CSV file and some fields contain a value like "1.8**e-5**, 8.139717345049093**e-39**" (exponent or scientific numbers). I need to store this value in a SQL real data type field (not float). But the maximum exponent supported by real is **e-38**.

But I need a mechanism to convert this string field to a real number through SSIS. Basically the e-39 or smaller values should be replaced as 0. and the rest should be stored properly.

I tried setting the data type to DT_R4 in flat file connection field mapping and that didn't help. I tried casting it to DT_R4 through a derived column and that didn't help too. When I check through Data Viewer still the value has the unsupported exponent value and it fails when I insert it to the SQL table.

Comment: Insert the string value in a stage table on your database then convert it with SQL. `SELECT CONVERT(REAL, '8.139717345049093e-39')` returns 0.

Comment: I cannot do that. I have to do this somehow through the SSIS package it self. :(

Comment: Is the number that you are receiving a valid number? Or is it data that has been outputted incorrectly into the CSV? Anyways, have you tried doing it in a script component?

Comment: write a c# / .net script, call it using ssis